# Using a DLL Compiled with a different compiler

Tags: c#, c, dll

I am currently writing a C# application that uses C++/CLI to take advantage of a library written in C that was not created by myself. This library is compiled into a DLL and then referenced in the C# project, inside of a C++ wrapper (long winded I know).

Here's the problem; if I compile the C library into a DLL using MinGW (a GCC makefile was supplied with the library) then the code works as it should and produces the correct output (this was tested via the command line). However, if I include all the library headers and source files into a C project in Visual Studio and compile it with the MSVC compiler, I get a `Read Access Violation` deep inside the libraries code.

Now I could (and probably should) debug the library to find out exactly what the problem is, but it is written in fairly low level C which I do not have much experience with; so my question is, if I compile the library into a DLL using MinGW, and then reference that DLL in a project that is compiled with MSVC, will that solve the issue?

Comment: Isn't [Platform Invocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx) better in this case?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: @VisualVincent I did try to use PInvoke, but I could not for the life of me get it working. So I wrote a quick C++ wrapper for the C code and C++/CLI worked almost immediately.

Comment: As long as the methods of your C dll is wrapped in an `extern "C"` block and you get the parameters and such right, P/Invoke should work.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are on your way. This is your opportunity to become an expert developer - there are no shortcuts. Step through the code in Visual Studio, when you get to code you don't understand, investigate. If you spend more than 2 hours trying to understand something specific, take a break, pivot your investigation (i.e. try following a different lead, try a different search term). As much as possible, keep going, don't let yourself get stuck. C language is specifically transparent - there's no magic. You can do it. You'll be glad you did. It's worth the effort to understand C in particular. Anything. ANYTHING you can do in code can be done (explained) in C language. C is the rosetta stone of computer languages. Get started. Let us know how it goes.